# How to upload temporary saved image to php in python

Tags: php, python, python-3.x

I have a php page that enabled user to upload their photos.

I wanted to write a python script that are able to download image from link (and save it into temp files) and upload it to the php.

Below is the php code (get from https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) - this php file have no problem, it is just handling user image uplaod - ():

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

And my python script:

```
import requests
import base64
import tempfile

def download_file_from_url(url):

        # Stream the image from the url
        try:
                request = requests.get(url, stream=True)
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
                # TODO: log error here
                return None

        if request.status_code != requests.codes.ok:
                # TODO: log error here
                return None

        # Create a temporary file
        lf = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()

        # Read the streamed image in sections
        for block in request.iter_content(1024 * 8):

                # If no more file then stop
                if not block:
                    break

                # Write image block to temporary file
                lf.write(block)


        return lf



url = "http://localhost/wlox/testwp/tryupload/processupload.php"

files = {'fileToUpload': download_file_from_url('https://cnet2.cbsistatic.com/img/hjo7_UY6ykIh_9cfttUZYaiF7V0=/770x433/2017/06/21/39c814c4-4909-43e8-aa0d-89eff3aced37/apple-macbook-12-inch-2017-01.jpg')}

r = requests.post(url, files=files)

print(r.text)
```

When I execute the python script, it shows

```
Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.Sorry, your file was not uploaded.
```

Can I know why? Thanks

Comment: Do some debugging. Add a `var_dump($_FILES);` in your PHP code and check what you're actually getting. I think you need to send it as form-data and add the file name as well or PHP won't have a filename to grab the extension from. Currently, you only seem to be sending the binary file contents.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I tried two type of method, one is actually saving the file in my computer before uploading it, and the var dump shows correct result with the size of the file being the size of the uploaded file, however, the temp files only shows 0. Can I know why?

Comment: You didn't really respond to my points. In the var_dump(), did you see the name of the file (which you don't pass in your post but are basing the file type on)? Have you tried posting the files as form-data?

Comment: yes the i see the name of the file which started with tmp.

Comment: That's not the original name. That's the path to the temporary file. And as you can see, it doesn't contain any file extension. When you upload a file, PHP reads the file contents and stores it in a temporary file, which you then manually need to move to your upload-folder and rename it to the real filename (including extension). As I've mentioned several times, you need to either post using form-data (where you include the actual filename) or you need to somehow pass the _original_ filename in the request as well and use that. Since I just seem to repeat myself, I'm out...